# Touch events stop firing

Tags: javascript, svg, touch

Im trying to make an interactive SVG with Javascript.
I subscribed to every touch event of Document and want to handle them.

But after `TouchStart` event i redraw svg element and that somehow cause an issue:
`TouchMove` and `TouchEnd` stops firing until manipulation finished.

Btw I dont use `preventDefault`;

Comment: What do you mean by "redraw"? If your "redrawing" involves replacing the object, then the event listeners on the original objects will naturally stop functioning as intended. We'd need to see your code to say more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is enough to solve problem. We indeed replace some elements and properties of SVG from code. I just didn't expect that behavior. So, document events depend on sub-elements.